# How to create a new column in a DataFrame and move select data from the first column to the new column

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is 860x1 and I want create a new column that shifts data from first column to the second.

example:

```
      Lyrics
0.    name
1.    lyric
2.    name
3.    lyric
4.    name
5.    lyric
```

What I need is:

```
      Lyrics     Title
0.    lyric      name
1.    lyric      name
2.    lyric      name
3.    lyric      name
```

The odd index numbers are lyrics and even are names. How can I move the names to a new column using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slice indexing to grab every second row with either 0 or 1 as the offset from the start:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Lyrics'] = lyrics.iloc[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)
df['Title'] = lyrics.iloc[0::2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I think you must add `drop=True` for `reset_index` and don't need `iloc`

Comment: Thank you this ended up working. I did have to put in the drop=True and I removed the iloc to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,2))[[1,0]].rename(columns={1:"Lyrics", 0:"Title"})
```

a fun point:)

1. my code time: `1.81 ms ± 480`
2. BENY's code time: `2.66 ms ± 741 µs`
3. creanion's code time: `1.99 ms ± 578 µs`

run on data with 10,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `groupby`

```
out = pd.concat([y.reset_index(drop=True) for _ , y in df.groupby(df.index%2)['Lyrics']],axis=1,keys= ['Title','Lyrics'])
Out[49]: 
  Title Lyrics
0  name  lyric
1  name  lyric
2  name  lyric
```